# Full access to admin panel

Tags: users

So I have an access to the site as 'content' manager (at least it says content in the username field when im into dupal panel). And they asked me to change the menu a bit. But all I can do is making a limited amount of actions by default (like adding a page or a product info, etc.). There's no link to edit block or menu. As I consumed there're different types of access cos as I've seen in documentation the real administrative panel is quite functional. Am I right? So I asked for the FTP access and I got it but all I can do is changing some style rules in css and injector-css. So as I understand I can change html only in the real admin panel, right? Can I do something without that panel just having an access to FTP? And if yes, where I can find it in root folder? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they ask you to update menus then they should give your user role the permissions to make menu changes, whether you have access to FTP doesn't really matter in this case.